# RailsAdmin - Export Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

Recently I started using `Rails Admin` for creating admin panel.

I am using devise for authentication. I need to access current_user in export action.

For virtual attributes in `formatted_value` block I cannot reach current_user via `bindings[:controller]._current_user` or `bindings[:view]._current_user`. Inside bindings there is only object `(bindings[:object])` and `bindings[:controller]` does not exist.

How to access `current_user` in export action?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you get the current user on a block inside a model configuration

```
rails_admin do
  show do
    field :user do
      value do
         bindings[:view].current_user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Inside an action you should be able to access 
current_user

```
module RailsAdmin
  module Config
    module Actions
      class Export < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
        [...]
        register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
            @user = current_user
            redirect_to back_or_index
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you don't make sure you specify it on the rails admin config

```
# config/initializers/rails_admin.rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, this is not working. I already mention that `bindings` contains only **object** key, therefore i cannot use `bindings[:view]` or `bindings[:controller]`

Comment: Thanks for the update. Here is the case; i have tried defining `@user` variable option and `@user` is nil inside the `formatted_value` block. Otherwise, i already defined `config.current_user_method(&:current_user)`. I think cause of problem is not export action. I think its related with **virtual_attribute** and **formatted_value** block while exporting.